# Lost admin ability to edit profiles

Tags: permissions, sandbox, profile

Before, I was able to edit all profiles, but now i lost the edit button to profiles.
Is there is any setting involved in this or did I do something wrong?

I am a system administrator,  I am able to do any thing with other profiles and user, but now I lost ability to edit the other profiles in sandbox, but in production I am still able to do so.

Myprofile view is also changed .it is showing like permission set view as profile view

Comment: What profile do you have? It may be that someone removed that ability from your profile or maybe they enabled one of the newer UIs that relocated the profiles?

Comment: it is a system admin standard profile

Answer (score 3):

The new UI changes how profiles are created and edited, but the full functionality still exists; you simply have to navigate to the appropriate areas. However, for now, if you want to get back to the old view, visit Setup > Customize > User Interface and turn off the new profile UI. I would recommend you get comfortable with the new UI before too long, however, since that is likely to become the standard UI over the next few releases.